# Spring Oauth2. Password encoder is not set in DaoAuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm quite new to Spring Oauth and Spring Security. I'm trying to use the client_credentials flow in my project. For now i managed to user my own CustomDetailsService in order to fetch client_id and password (secret) from a database that already exists in my system. The only problem is that I cannot change the password encoder in DaoAuthenticationProvider that is used by AuthorizationServer - it is set by default to PlaintextPasswordEncoder. I wasn't able to configure it the way, that it would use for example SHAPasswordEncoder. It always uses the plaintext encoder. I probably don't understand the flow well enough, as I am a newbie in Spring.

Here's some code of mine (with not working configuration of DaoAuthenticationProvider):

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "restservice";

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/register/**");

}

@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return daoAuthenticationProvider;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new ShaPasswordEncoder();
}

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyCustomClientDetailsService myCustomClientDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints)
            throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceServerTokenServices defaultTokenServices() {
        final DefaultTokenServices defaultTokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        defaultTokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
        defaultTokenServices.setTokenStore(tokenStore());
        return defaultTokenServices;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.withClientDetails(myCustomClientDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public MyCustomClientDetailsService detailsService() {
        return new MyCustomClientDetailsService();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    ...
}
}
```

And the custom ClientDetailsService class:

```
public class MyCustomClientDetailsService implements ClientDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Override
public ClientDetails loadClientByClientId(String clientId) throws ClientRegistrationException {

    User fan = userService.getFan(clientId);

    if (fan == null) {
        throw new NoSuchClientException("No client with requested id: " + clientId);
    } 

    BaseClientDetails details = new BaseClientDetails(clientId, restservice, "write", "client_credentials", "USER");

    details.setClientSecret(fan.getEncodedPassword()); 

    return details;
}
}
```

The encodedPassword that is taken from my UserService is always a bad Credential, as DaoAuthenticationProvider has a PlaintextPasswordEncoder set by default.

What am i missing there?
Is it possible to set the password encoder in the DaoAuthenticationProvider that is used for checking the credentials here? Or do I have to write my own AuthenticationProvider, that would check it the way i want?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem Did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The solution I found to the problem is to override `configure` on `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
    oauthServer.passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}
```

Comment: Note that I also had to set it in the `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` override of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` subclass like this: `auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)` otherwise only the client_secret was encoded, but not the users' password.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Been looking into it for weeks

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to configure spring authentication with another pass encoder then use this configuration.

```xml
<bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder"/>

 <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="authenticationService">
       <password-encoder ref ="encoder" /> 

          <!--   <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN"/>
            </user-service> -->
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

**Note:- During create user you need to encrypt userpassword with this same password Encoder class.**

Comment: Am I not doing the same thing but using the Java based configuration. I am setting the authenticationProvider:
  
auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());

 that is previously configured to use SHAPasswordEncoder. Or am I wrong about this?

Comment: you can configure with any passwordEncoder. just remember that user password should be encrypted using same passwordEncoder class encode method.

Comment: in XML Configuration  we can refer another passwordEncoder ,                                       <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.providers.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
  <property name="userDetailsService" ref="inMemoryDaoImpl"/>
  <property name="saltSource" ref bean="saltSource"/>
  <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
</bean>

Comment: But the problem is that I try to set the encoder in DaoAuthenticationProvider, but it isn't set at all - i debugged it. I am aware that i need to use the same encoder during creating user but it is not the problem here.