# Foreseeing issues when upgrading from Spring 4.2 to Spring 5.0.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

On my current project we are using Spring 4.2 (core, aop, beans, web , webmvc, etc).

What are the major problems we could encounter when upgrading from Spring 4.2 to Spring 5.0.5? How backward compatible would Spring Security 4.2 be with Spring 5.0.5?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without knowing which functionalities and features of Spring your project relies on.

I'd suggest to start by reviewing official changelogs and release notes to determine the affected parts of your project.
[What's New in Spring Framework 5.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x) might be a good starting point.

Especially watch out for removed features and APIs.

There also is a [Spring Integration 4.3 to 5.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-4.3-to-5.0-Migration-Guide).

Answer (score 0):

while upgrading to Spring 4.2.7 i faced below two issues

1. Get and Delete requests containing ";" and "%" character will fail with 500 response because of the HttpFirewall restrictions. You can refer to below link for solution.

[Getting 500 response in Spring 5 when url contains semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51477261/getting-500-response-in-spring-5-when-url-contains-semicolon)

2. Spring 5 needs default password encoder otherwise it will throw below exception
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null
   You can refer to below link for solution.

[Spring Security 5 : There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654143/spring-security-5-there-is-no-passwordencoder-mapped-for-the-id-null)