# Spring Boot, Spring-Security - BcrypPasswordEncoder in new component-based security configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to use the new Component-Based (Without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter) configuration and setted up my Security Configuration as follow:

**SecurityConfiguration.java file**

```
package com.tito.userservice.security;

import com.tito.userservice.filter.CustomAuthenticationFilter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;


@Configuration @EnableWebSecurity @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder;


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    //----------------HTTP SECURITY CONFIG-------------------------------------
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
                

        http.addFilter(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(authManagerBuilder.getOrBuild()));

        return http.build();
    }

    //----------------HTTP SECURITY CONFIG-------------------------------------



}
```

but when I run the application and try to log a user the following error appears even though I have the BCryptPasswordEncoder as a bean in my SecurityConfiguration:

**Error Stack Trace***

```
2022-08-16 21:02:04.220 ERROR 13112 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
        at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder$UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:289) ~[spring-security-crypto-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:237) ~[spring-security-crypto-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:76) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:147) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182) ~[spring-security-core-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at com.tito.userservice.filter.CustomAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(CustomAuthenticationFilter.java:43) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.2.jar:5.7.2]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Which is the correct way to set up the PasswordEncoder in the new component-configuration?

**Edit: adding login logic**

**AppUserService interface**

```
package com.tito.userservice.services;

import com.tito.userservice.domain.AppUser;
import com.tito.userservice.domain.Role;

import java.util.List;

public interface AppUserService {
    AppUser saveUser(AppUser user);
    Role saveRole(Role role);

    void addRoleToUser(String username, String roleName);

    AppUser getUser(String username);
    List<AppUser>getUsers();

}
```

and the **AppUserServiceImplementation**:

```
package com.tito.userservice.services;

import com.tito.userservice.domain.AppUser;
import com.tito.userservice.domain.Role;
import com.tito.userservice.repo.AppUserRepo;
import com.tito.userservice.repo.RoleRepo;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

@Service @RequiredArgsConstructor @Transactional @Slf4j
public class AppUserServiceImpl implements AppUserService, UserDetailsService {

    private final AppUserRepo appUserRepo;
    private final RoleRepo roleRepo;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        AppUser user =appUserRepo.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null){
            log.error("User not found in the database");
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found in the databse");
        }else {
            log.info("User found in the database: {}",username);
        }
        Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        user.getRoles().forEach(role -> {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        });
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    }

    @Override
    public AppUser saveUser(AppUser user) {
        log.info("Saving new user {} to the database",user.getName());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        return appUserRepo.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public Role saveRole(Role role) {
        log.info("Saving new role {} to the database",role.getName());
        return roleRepo.save(role);
    }

    @Override
    public void addRoleToUser(String username, String roleName) {
        log.info("Adding role {} to user {}",roleName,username );

        //real life could be good, or must be good, to do validation of below
        AppUser user = appUserRepo.findByUsername(username);
        Role role = roleRepo.findByName(roleName);
        user.getRoles().add(role);
    }

    @Override
    public AppUser getUser(String username) {
        log.info("Fetching user {}",username );
        return appUserRepo.findByUsername(username);
    }

    @Override
    public List<AppUser> getUsers() {
        log.info("Fetching all users");
        return appUserRepo.findAll();
    }


}
```

**Edit2: added CustomAuthenticationFilter.java code**

**CustomAuthenticationFilter.java**

```
package com.tito.userservice.filter;


import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.tito.userservice.domain.AppUser;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


@Slf4j
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {


    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public CustomAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager){
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }
    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        log.info("Username is: {}", username); log.info("Password is: {}",password);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,password);
        return  authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();
        Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256("secret".getBytes()); //not for use in production, need to pass as encrypted and then decrypt here
        String access_token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() +10*60*1000))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .withClaim("roles",user.getAuthorities().stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .sign(algorithm);
        String refresh_token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(user.getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() +30*60*1000))
                .withIssuer(request.getRequestURL().toString())
                .sign(algorithm);
        response.setHeader("access_token",access_token);
        response.setHeader("refresh_token",refresh_token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code sample you are using to log in the user?

Comment: @Shail sorry for it, just added it.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654143/spring-security-5-there-is-no-passwordencoder-mapped-for-the-id-null

Comment: thanks you a lot, but it does not works because there are using  WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and the new component-based configuration does not use it

Comment: In your SecurityConfiguration.java remove the declaration ```private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;``` that could be a issue as no bean is defined for it.

Comment: @TTT2 please add the code from your CustomAuthenticationFilter, because judging by the stacktrace the exception is raised there when AuthenticationManager is trying to authenticate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the stacktrace I assume your `CustomAuthenticationFilter` calls `AuthenticationManager.authenticate()` method on a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` object. That, by default, calls `DaoAuthenticationProvider`, which is created with a `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`, containing 11 password encoders, and which is trying to match passwords with this encoder (not your `BCryptPasswordEncoder` bean).

This `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` tries to match stored password, retrieved from your `UserDetailsService`, and **it assumes your password is stored with a key (prefix)**, like this:

```
{bcrypt}encodedPassword
```

You've registered a bean of type `BCryptPasswordEncoder` and you're encoding your password with it, so passwords are stored without {bcrypt} prefix (just the encoded password is stored), and when calling `AuthenticationManager.authenticate()` mentioned `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` sees null prefix and cannot find the corresponding `PasswordEncoder` in a map - that's what the error message is about.

So you can define a `PasswordEncoder` bean as a `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`, which, by default, uses `BCryptPasswordEncoder` to encode passwords.

Like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

That way stored passwords will have {prefix} and `DaoAuthenticationProvider` will be able to match passwords.
Also I advise to remove the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` field from your `SecurityConfiguration` class - you don't need it there.

Also you can stuck with bean cycle dependencies, because your `UserDetailsService` injects `PasswordEncoder`, and `PasswordEncoder` is defined in a configuration, where `UserDetailsService` is injected, so you might also need refactoring.
For example, try to extract `UserDetailsService`:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final AppUserRepo appUserRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // your logic here
        return new User(username, password, authorities);
    }
}
```

Or define a bean of this type `UserDetailsService` right in your `SecurityConfiguration` class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private final AppUserRepo appUserRepo;
    // other fields

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> {
            // your logic here
            return new User(username, password, authorities);        
        };
    }
}
```

Also you can:

- instead of a custom filter create your own login endpoint, where you can check password matches using `BCryptPasswordEncoder` directly;
- create your own `AuthenticationProvider` with a `BCryptPasswordEncoder` as a password encoder and use it in your `CustomAuthenticationFilter` to authenticate user.

Comment: also additional useful information can be found in this article: https://spring.io/blog/2017/11/01/spring-security-5-0-0-rc1-released#password-encoding

Comment: I did what you recommend step by step, first define the PassWordEncoder as `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`, deleted the `BCryptPasswordEncoder ` ran the application and got stuck for circular beans cycle dependency as u said, i deleted the UserDetailService injection in the configuration and the app worked, thanks you a lot, also the last part was not neccesary, i.e refactoring or defain the `UserDetailsService` bean, the app worked with the past steps

Answer (score -2):

In `spring-security-core:5.0.0.RC1`, the default `PasswordEncoder` is built as a `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`. When you store the users in memory, you are providing the passwords in plain text and when trying to retrieve the encoder from the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` to validate the password it can't find one that matches the way in which these passwords were stored.

Use this way to create users instead.

```
User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("user").roles("USER").build();
```

Comment: that's not the issue, because author doesn't use in-memory authentication at all - he encodes the password with the BCryptPasswordEncoder, declared as a bean.